# Linux - Execute command withing CLI program

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I tried searching I couldn't get answer to my question, maybe because I am not sure how to ask it correctly, so I apologize in advance.

 I am trying to execute chain of commands in bash script eg:

```
run mysql > type help > exit

root@ubuntu:# mysql
mysql> help
mysql> exit
root@ubuntu:#
```

How can I achieve this in bash script? 
I have tried operands ||, &&, ; all this eg:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql || help || exit
```

Didn't work. It executes commands after each other.

Comment: Do you mean you want to run a number of MySQL commands in order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a heredoc to pass some text, which the command will read as if it were a file:

```
mysql <<EOF
help
exit
EOF
```

Alternatively, in bash you can use a herestring, which achieves a similar effect to piping commands over standard input without creating any additional subshells:

```
mysql <<< $'help\nexit'
# or on other shells
printf 'help\nexit\n' | mysql
```

Note that the `exit` isn't really necessary, as `mysql` will exit when it runs out of input anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
mysql << EOF
help
exit
EOF
```

This will start the mysql command then pipe the help and exit commands to mysql's stdin which is effectively the same as typing them directly

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is run a number of MySQL commands in order.

The heredoc approach mentioned by others is the way to do in a Shell script.

Perhaps you just want to run the same MySQL commands from the command line. If so, the MySQL command line tool takes as its default argument a file containing commands such as `help` and other SQL commands.

1. Create a file (Say `myfile.sql`) and edit contents:

   ```
   help
   select * from mytable
   ```
2. Save file
3. Pass file to mysql:

   ```
   mysql myfile.sql
   ```

There's no need to call `exit`